# How to remove required second password in FOSUserBundle, Symfony 3?

Tags: symfony, passwords, fosuserbundle

I try to overwrite default **FOS** registration form, and I didn't have second password field. How I can remove it from required fields IN **FOS**, so I will not see the error like `fos_user.password.blank`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Official docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/overriding_forms.html) for the rescue!

For example, if you want to add a `name` field to your registration form:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name');
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
}
```

There is another key paragraph there:

- `If you don't want to reuse the fields added in FOSUserBundle by default, you can omit the getParent method and configure all fields yourself.`

So you can omit the `getParent` method, and instead add all your desired fields in the `buildForm` method.

Comment: Thank you very much, I thought there will be some more nicer and easier way then just rebuild form my self. Some unset('password2')

Comment: FosUserBundle creates an event at the beginning of a registration process. The event is FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_INITIALIZE.
You can create an event listener, and make the needed  manipulations with submitted data, for example, make second password form field and fill it with a copy of submitted password.

Answer (score 0):

So there is an easier way.
    ....

```
class ProfileFormType extends AbstractType
{
    ....

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\ProfileFormType';
    }
```

> $builder->remove('email');

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39282012/2309309